# Prove that if $(x_0,y_0)$ is local extremum, then the second order derivatives are all zero.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let A be open in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f \in C^2$ and $D_{11}f(x,y)+D_{22}f(x,y)=0 $ for any $x,y \in A$. Prove that if $(x_0,y_0)$ is local extremum of f, then all second order derivatives are zero in $(x_0, y_0).$

Consider the hessian matrix of $f$ in $(x_0,y_0),$ $Hf(x_0,y_0)=\begin{bmatrix}D_{11}f(x_0,y_0) & D_{12}f(x_0,y_0)\\D_{21}f(x_0,y_0) & D_{22}f(x_0,y_0)\end{bmatrix}$.

$(x_0,y_0)$ is a local extremum of $f$ so it is either a local maximum or a local minimum and thus $Hf(x_0,y_0)$ is either semidefinite positive (its eigenvalues are all non negative) or semidefinite negative (its eigenvalues are all non positive).

$D_{11}f(x_0,y_0)+D_{22}f(x_0,y_0)=0 \rightarrow D_{11}f(x_0,y_0)=-D_{22}f(x_0,y_0)$ so:

$det\begin{bmatrix}D_{11}f(x_0,y_0) - \lambda & D_{12}f(x_0,y_0)\\D_{21}f(x_0,y_0) & D_{22}f(x_0,y_0) - \lambda\end{bmatrix} = det\begin{bmatrix}D_{11}f(x_0,y_0) - \lambda & D_{12}f(x_0,y_0)\\D_{21}f(x_0,y_0) & -D_{11}f(x_0,y_0) - \lambda\end{bmatrix}$;

$f \in C^2$ so $D_{12}f(x_0,y_0)=D_{21}f(x_0,y_0)$ and then:

$det\begin{bmatrix}D_{11}f(x_0,y_0) - \lambda & D_{12}f(x_0,y_0)\\D_{21}f(x_0,y_0) & -D_{11}f(x_0,y_0) - \lambda\end{bmatrix}=det\begin{bmatrix}D_{11}f(x_0,y_0) - \lambda & D_{12}f(x_0,y_0)\\D_{12}f(x_0,y_0) & -D_{11}f(x_0,y_0) - \lambda\end{bmatrix}$ =

$(D_{11}f(x_0,y_0)- \lambda)(-D_{11}f(x_0,y_0) - \lambda) - 2D_{12}f(x_0,y_0) = 0$;

$(D_{11}f(x_0,y_0)- \lambda)(-D_{11}f(x_0,y_0) - \lambda) - 2D_{12}f(x_0,y_0) = -D_{11}f(x_0,y_0)^2-\lambda D_{11}f(x_0,y_0)+\lambda D_{11}f(x_0,y_0)+ \lambda^2 - 2D_{12}f(x_0,y_0) = -D_{11}f(x_0,y_0)^2+ \lambda^2 - 2D_{12}f(x_0,y_0) = 0$;

So $\lambda^2 = 2D_{12}f(x_0,y_0)+D_{11}f(x_0,y_0)^2$;

I don't know how to continue from here or if this is the right path. Any help?

Comment: All those coordinates make me dizzy. $f(X_0+h)=f(X_0)+h^tHh+o(|h|^2)$. If $X_0$  is a local extremum, then $H$ is semi-definite (positive or negative). This means that its determinant has to be greater than or equal to zero. If the trace is zero, then the eigenvalues would be either both zero or both imaginary. Since the matrix is symmetric they can't be imaginary. Therefore the determinant is zero. Determinant zero, trace zero, and symmetric ... the matrix is zero.

Comment: if $D_{12}f(x_0,y_0)$ is not zero then we will get two roots for $\lambda^2$, one positive and one negative. But you already showed this cannot be the case given the assumptions, either both roots are positive or both are negative.

Comment: @TonyS.F. but if $D_{12} = -\frac{1}{2}{D_{11}^2}$ and both are non zero, wouldn't we still have that $\lambda=0$ and $H$ is semidefinite?